# I can't install any package using pip or pipenv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask

I want to install many packages for my project like `flask` or `psycopg2` or `flask-sqlachermy` but I can't.

When I use the `pip` I receive this error message:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\Lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe\\_speedups.c'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

When I use the `pipenv` I receive this error message:

```
[36mERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\.virtualenvs\\ASUS-mVsQ382S\\Lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe\\_speedups.c'
Check the permissions.
```

I tried to install again the markupsafe package because I thint that it is the source of the problem but it's not working.

Comment: It says _Consider using the `--user` option_ have you tried that? Python was installed using one user's rights (likely administrator) and other users (like your regular login) can't update. If you want to install for everyone, run as admin. If only for your user, use --user/

Comment: you created a virtualenv, but did you activate it ?  I can't see the venv name int he prompt like : (venv) C:\path\to\project\directory> ?    I don't know if ti will solve...

Comment: Thank you guys for your support ! I tried running as administrator or using the --user but it's also not working , i think i have a proble with the folder markupsafe in the sites-packages of Python but i don't now how to solve the problem !

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Try to supply **--user** flag on your pip install command, otherwise it does a global installation and seems you don't have permissions for that.

Comment: Thank you for your support ! I tried runnig the command with --user but it's not working ! i think i have a problem with the folder markupsafe in the sites-packages of Python, but i checked the permission for this folder and it was normal .

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide more details about what you tried and what the permissions and ACLs look like for the directory you think is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

If it is telling you that you don't have permission, then it is likely that you would need to be an administrator while using the command prompt

Try right clicking on the command prompt app before opening and click 'Run as Administrator'. This should fix the problem

Comment: Thank you for your support ! I tried runnig as an administrator but it's also not working !